# Windows Server 2016 C# Launched process window is blank and unusable

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, windows-server-2016

I am running an automated test using C# and Coded UI Tests on Window Server 2016.  I am using the process.start method to launch an installer but when the test launches the installer, the window is blank and cannot be used either by the test or manually.

This does not happen when I launch the installer manually (works fine) or on any other OS (only happens on Server 2016).

Everything is running as admin.  I have updated windows itself and video drivers.

Here is the code used to launch the installer:

```
        public void LaunchUnifiedDashboardInstaller(bool upgrade = false)
    {
        string pathtoInstaller = "";
        // Get path to installer
        if (upgrade == false)
        {
            pathtoInstaller = TestRunSettings.TestSetting.GetPathToInstallers();
        }
        else if (upgrade == true)
        {
            pathtoInstaller = TestRunSettings.TestSetting.GetPathToUpgradeInstaller();
        }
        //string pathtoInstaller = @"E:\";
        Console.WriteLine("LaunchUnifiedDashboardInstaller() - Path to installer is: " + pathtoInstaller);

        TestReport.WriteText("Launching Unified Dashboard setup .... ");

        //Server Installer
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(pathtoInstaller + @"\setup.exe");

        //proc.UseShellExecute = true;
        //proc.Verb = "runas";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
        TestReport.WriteText("Launching Unified Dashboard setup .... ");
    }
```

**screenshot of blank windows**

[image]

This one has me totally stumped.  Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Sort of.
This was happening using Server 2016 with all the available updates applied.

So I went back to the base original release of Server 2016 (from 2016) and turned off Windows update.  Lo and behold, it now works fine.  Something in a newer Windows version must have disagreed with Coded UI.